# Difference between two timestamps in hours minutes and seconds

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, momentjs, moment-timezone

I am trying to calculate the difference between two timestamp
"2020-03-18T17:34:45.856Z", "2020-03-18T16:34:45.856Z"
the difference should be like this: 2 hours 20min 30sec

I have tried using

```
return moment.utc(moment(startDate, 'HH:mm:ss').diff(moment(endDate, 'HH:mm:ss'))).format('HH:mm:ss');
```

m not sure how to get the desired format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get it manually using [Moment Duration](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/)

```js
const startDate = "2020-03-18T17:34:45.856Z";
const endDate = "2020-03-18T16:34:45.856Z";

const diff = moment(startDate).diff(moment(endDate));

const duration = moment.duration(diff);
const hrs = duration.hours();
const mins = duration.minutes();
const secs = duration.seconds();

console.log(hrs + "hours " + mins + "min " + secs + "sec");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```